# How to list on cv an article honored as national conference theme?

Tags: cv

Apologies for the unwieldy question title.

Essentially, a journal article I just published in the flagship journal of the national disciplinary association was very well received by its members. The article's ideas are now being made the organizing themes of the following year's annual conference.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how/where I might list this on my CV?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Yes, I've gotten confirmation from the organizers that this is the case. I'm also not asking about *whether* or not to list this, but *how* the best way to do so might be without incurring confusion. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's necessary to read the conference announcement to answer this question completely.

Comment: Will the conference announcement explicitly mention your paper? If so, then I think it's reasonable to mention that on your CV. But I wouldn't mention things that can't be objectively verified; in particular, I wouldn't say merely that the conference theme matches your article's ideas.

Comment: I think you have to convey this in few lines. The description can come after thet paper entry or in other section of your cv.